# JAVA EE & MVC

Tags: java-ee, mvc, java

Всем доброго времени суток!

Такой у меня вопрос:

Зачем MVC - объяснять и раскрывать не буду,и так понятно.

MVC  состоит из 3 компонентов - модель,представление,контроллер.

Как я понимаю, представление - это JSP, модель - это Servlet'ы . А вот контроллер - это JavaBean ?

И если я не прав - то в чем суть JavaBean ?

Answer (score 4):

Сервлеты - это, обычно, контроллер, т.к. именно здесь происходит обработка запросов и обращение к модели.

Модель - это предметная область, выраженная в сущностях и бизнес-логике. Соответственно модель может быть представлена куда более разнообразно, чем просто Java-класс.